# SwiftUI macOS List Row removing padding

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to display a row inside my ListView in SwiftUI for MacOS.
However, my issue is that the row contains padding around it. I would like to stretch it to the boundaries of my `ListView`.

Apple uses `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` in their example. However, that is only shown on iOS. For me, it is not working on macOS.

My row got a red border to visualize the issue. I want it to be stretched all the way to the boundaries of the List Row, so fill the whole blue row.
Is that possible in macOS?

Thanks in advance.

[image: preview]

Comment: Use a custom XIB/NIB file. It's much easier to manage that. then remove the separator lines.

Comment: show us the simplified code of your "ListView"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For now I've found only workaround (`.listRowInsets` should really do this work, so worth submitting feedback to Apple):

[image: demo]

```
struct TestListRow: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (0..<3) { i in
                HStack {
                    Text("Test row \(i)").font(.largeTitle)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.green)
            .border(Color.red)
            .padding(.horizontal, -8)   // << workaround !!
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 40)
        .border(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Working great .. where to report these bugs? @Asperi

Comment: This removes the spacing, but messes up the body completely. Overriding the `defaultMinListRowHeight` doesn't seem to be working nicely for me.

Comment: Hmm `defaultMinListRowHeight` and the insets seemed to fix the problem for me

Comment: It didn't work for me. Have you faced more issues ? I'm using the Xcode beta 
https://imgur.com/gallery/lJqY69f

Answer (score 0):

I added this code at end of the row and the padding was shrunk!!!

```
    Spacer()
    Text(" ")
    .padding()
```

Sample Code

```
import SwiftUI


struct testViews1: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (0..<3) { i in
                HStack {
                    Text("row \(i)")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 30)  
            }
        }
    }
}


struct testViews2: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (0..<3) { i in
                HStack {
                    Text("row \(i)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(" ")
                        .padding()   
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 30)
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct testViews_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testViews1()
            .frame(height: 150)
        testViews2()
            .frame(height: 150)

    }
}
```

output
[image]

It works with SwiftUI 1.