# SwiftUI List Rows fill width

Tags: list, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI 2.0, i have a List with some text (MacOS App)

```swift
typealias Row = String

@State var row: [Row] = ["1 Row with some content", "2 Some content", "3 Another Row"]

List(row, id: \.self) { content in
    Text(content)
        .truncationMode(.middle)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(Color.blue)
}
```

This leads to the following output in preview:

[image]

How can i make the rows fill all available space?
(Blue Frame of List should match blue background of text)

Adding a `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` to the List element, reduces the space, but not enough:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60727518/12299030?

Comment: has the same topic, but the solutions there do not work

Answer (score 6):

You can try with this:

```swift
    Text(content)
        .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
        .listRowBackground(Color.white.opacity(0))
```

Comment: .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)) did the trick

Comment: .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) looks better

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only solution to this at the moment is adding the ugly workaround

```swift
.padding(.horizontal, -15.0)
```

to the `List(...)`